# How to get the frequency of items in a list with the different length

Tags: r, list

Suppose I have the following list:

```
test<-list(c("a","b","c"),c("a"),c("c"))
>test
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

[[2]]
[1] "a"

[[3]]
[1] "c"
```

What do I do(or functions to use) to get the frequency of unique items in a list like this:?

```
a 2
b 1
c 2
```

I tried using table(test), but I get the following error

```
> table(test)
Error in table(test) : all arguments must have the same length
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
test <- list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("a"), c("c"))
# If you want count accross all elements
table(unlist(test))
## 
## a b c 
## 2 1 2 


# If you want seperate counts in each item of list
lapply(test, table)
## [[1]]
## 
## a b c 
## 1 1 1 
## 
## [[2]]
## 
## a 
## 1 
## 
## [[3]]
## 
## c 
## 1 
##
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `unlist` first

```
table(unlist(test))
```